# Adjust custom cell's object property through heightForRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a custom cell. In it is a `UILabel`. Is there a way I to adjust the labels height through `heightForRow...`, not at `cellForRow...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` there is no cell yet, and there are no subviews.

All changes should be done either (1) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, or (2) within a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.